# FineUploader - No responseJSON in IE9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-9, fine-uploader

I'm having some weird issues using FineUploader in IE9 - the file upload will go through, be processed on the server as expected, but then no responseJSON will be passed through to the complete event.

I'm not doing anything particularly complex, code snippet as follows:

```
    $('#upload').fineUploader({
        debug: true,
        button: $('#upload-button'),
        uploaderType: 'basic',
        request: {
            endpoint: '*snip*'                
        },
        multiple: false,
        sizeLimit: 4194304,
}).bind('complete', function (event, id, fileName, response) {            
        /* response doesn't contain anything it should at this point */
    })
```

There's also the following error in my javascript log:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Error when attempting to access iframe during handling of upload response (Access is denied.
```

Though I'm not sure why this is the case, since again, I'm not really doing anything complex.

I'm working in an MVC4 environment, and I'm able to pretty consistently reproduce the bug on a new project.

Thanks in advance, I'm out of ideas right now.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you are making a cross-origin upload request.  You'll need to account for this in your code by ensuring your server returns the proper response.  If you don't intend to make a cross-origin upload request, then you will need to take a closer look at your request endpoint value, or your environment.

Cross-origin uploads are a bit tricky in IE9 and older.  All of this is explained in the [Fine Uploader blog post on CORS](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/).  Here is some relevant info from the blog:

> An incoming upload request was sent via a form submission inside of a
>   hidden iframe if the request does not have an X-Requested-With header,
>   or if the X-Requested-With header has a value other than
>   “XMLHttpRequest”. Handling cross-domain iframe/form-submit-initiated
>   uploads (in browsers that do not support the File API) is a bit tricky
>   for Fine Uploader. I’ve done my best to make it as simple as possible
>   for developers/integrators, though. Your response for iframe based
>   request (such as required when using IE8 or IE9), will look very
>   similar to your normal response, except it must have a Content-Type
>   header value of “text/html”, and your response must import a helper
>   javascript file via a &ltscript&gt tag immediately preceding your
>   valid JSON response. For example:
>
> ```
> "{\"success\": true, \"uuid\":\"9da17ad5-ad6a-40cd-81b5-226e837db45b\"}<script src=\"http://<YOUR_SERVER_DOMAIN>/iframe.xss.response-<VERSION>.js/"></script>"
> ```
>
> All cross-domain iframe-initiated responses must end with the script
>   tag above, and the valid JSON portion MUST include the UUID of the
>   associated file. Note that you must host the iframe.xss.response.js
>   file on an accessible server and reference it in the &ltscript&gt tag
>   accordingly. When the contents of your response is returned to the
>   iframe tracked by Fine Uploader, the associated javascript file
>   imported by the script tag above will be executed, and will pass the
>   JSON portion of your response to the uploader via window.postMessage